# ¿Por qué no puedo instanciar valores de mi provider?

Tags: flutter

Verás lo que quiero es llamar a la variable de mi provider, que en este caso es:

```
Icon _hearticon = const Icon(
    Icons.favorite_border,
  );
```

y también el método que cambia la forma del icono cuando se presiona.

```
void changeHeart() {
    if (_hearticon.icon == Icons.favorite_border) {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite,
      );
    } else {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite_border,
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

aquí el provider completo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HeartIconState with ChangeNotifier {
  Icon _hearticon = const Icon(
    Icons.favorite_border,
  );
  void changeHeart() {
    if (_hearticon.icon == Icons.favorite_border) {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite,
      );
    } else {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite_border,
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Icon get hearticon => _hearticon;

  set hearticon(Icon value) {
    _hearticon = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

y la forma en que los estoy llamando:

```
IconButton(
   icon: Heart.hearticon,
   color: Colors.red,
   iconSize: 25.0,
  onPressed: Heart.changeHeart,
           ),
```

Ya lo había hecho así cuando estaba manipulando el estado de un color para cambiar de negro a blanco y viceversa.
agrego aqui los errores. subi una fotografia porque son muchos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He intentado replicar exactamente tú código y funciona correctamente.
Aségurate de haber inyectado el Provider HeartIconState correctamente antes de utilizarlo. ¿Puedes agregar el error?
Lo ejecuté de la siguiente forma:

```
#Clase provider
class HeartProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Icon _hearticon = const Icon(
    Icons.favorite_border,
  );
  Icon get hearticon => _hearticon;
 void changeHeart() {
    if (_hearticon.icon == Icons.favorite_border) {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite,
      );
    } else {
      _hearticon = const Icon(
        Icons.favorite_border,
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
#Clase main
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => HeartProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'SWAPI',
        initialRoute: 'login',
        routes: getApplicationRoutes(),
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
          primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(238, 219, 0, 1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
#Widget
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _heartProvider = Provider.of<HeartProvider>(context);
    return IconButton(
              icon: _heartProvider.hearticon,
              color: Colors.red,
              iconSize: 25.0,
              onPressed: _heartProvider.changeHeart,
            );
  }
}
```

Comment: compare mi codigo con el tuyo y parecen ser iguales. solo que el tuyo no tiene el setter. ademas sigue sin funcionar. edite la pregunta para agregar los errores. serias tan amable de porfavor revisarla?

Comment: el error estaba en que faltaba el child de el align

Comment: Bueno, no he agregado el set ya que en el método changeHeart()  al final estás utilizando el notifyListeners(), y realmente no estás utilizando el set en tú código podrías agregar dónde inyectas el provider?